# How to select "print on both sides" in MS Word 2013 vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'd like to be able to programmatically select the double sided button in MS Word 2013 printpreview in backoffice view via vba.

I am unable to get the PCL6 code to work with our sharp MFC. Some documents I want to have it print double sided by default but not on all documents. I can't find the ExecuteMso button for this as the backoffice view doesn't seem to be accessible via vba code. 
Perhaps using WinAPI would work or sendkeys but I think that's messy and unreliable.

[image: Backoffice view of Print Preview with double sided option highlighted]

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/230743/howto-set-duplex-printing-for-word-automation

Comment: Thanks Masoud I saw that work-around but this is not what I'm asking. It is a way to program duplex printing, however, what I am trying to do is select the button in my screenshot without using sendkeys. Not the answer.

Comment: I don't have the problems yo mentioned here and the comment section of the answer below; But, `SendKey` is an option. Not the best, but works probably.

Comment: Yes Masoud, I am considering Sendkeys as a last resort because it is typically unreliable and subject to interference from the user if they press keys or move the mouse, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found a workaround for duplex Printing. Word doesn't support the option for Automatic duplex printing rather it is printer specific which loads the options if a printer supports it.

- Install a copy version of the printer driver on your pc. I found great help for this from [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/362957/how-to-install-the-same-printer-twice-with-different-settings-on-windows/#:%7E:text=To%20find%20this%20information%2C%20head,select%20when%20adding%20the%20printer.).
- Follow the procedure and install the driver. Rename it (Use Duplex for easy understanding).
- Go to printing preference and set the duplex setting as default.
- Now make that printer active in your VBA code.

  `ActivePrinter = "Brother DCP Duplex"`

  ```
  Application.PrintOut FileName:="", Range:=wdPrintRangeOfPages, Item:= _ 
      wdPrintDocumentWithMarkup, Copies:=1, Pages:="s1", PageType:= _
      wdPrintAllPages, Collate:=True, Background:=True, PrintToFile:=False, _
      PrintZoomColumn:=0, PrintZoomRow:=0, PrintZoomPaperWidth:=0, _
      PrintZoomPaperHeight:=0
  ```
- No need for `ManualDuplexPrint:=False`.

I tried it myself and works perfectly.

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1):

You can control printing on one side or both sides with an option called: `ManualDuplexPrint`. Set it to `False` and it will print both sided.

Let's say that you want to print the whole document both sided. You would write:

```
Sub test()
    ThisDocument.PrintOut Range:=wdPrintAllDocument, ManualDuplexPrint:=False
End Sub
```

Please don't forget to hit the check mark next to the question if this is the answer! :)

Comment: Sorry friend but "manual duplex" is not what I want. With that option, I have to go to the MFC and put the paper back into the side feed tray then go back to the computer and press ok to print. What I am looking for is very specifically changing the printing to "Print on both sides" as my screenshot displays. As you can see the screenshot does not show Manual selected. Not the answer.

Comment: @user65795 I understand what you want. I personally tried on our own computer and printer and it did print ON BOTH SIDES without me turning the paper or anything like that. Did you try the code at all?

Comment: Also are you sure that your printer has the capability of handling printing on both sides? It may sound a dumb question, but if it is old it is possible there is no way of doing that at all

Comment: I tried the code ibo but it printed the first side then popped up a box asking me to put the paper in the side tray and press ok. So it is technically "Manual duplex" but not "print on both sides." I appreciate your effort and I was aware of this procedure but it is not yet what I'm looking for.

Comment: when you set both sides using the print dialog does it print on both sides automatically? if so, then I can look further

Comment: For reference, I was trying to accomplish something along the lines of using Ececutemso like this method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862419.aspx

Comment: yes I can set print both sides in the properties of the printer, but when I do that it has to be done manually and also switched back to single sided after each time I print. It can be very confusing for users trying to implement that approach.

Comment: It seems there are some other factors here that you should take into account such as the version of your word and also the type of printer etc. You have not posted a code, have you tried to record a macro and go through the code and see where VBA sets Print On Both Sides? Depending on the version of your word, you can actually set Page Setup and the printer will be set automatically to your setup from word

Comment: Hi lbo the title of my post says Word 2013. I don't have code because there isn't any code that will access the back office area that I know of. The only possibility is using the idMSO parameter for that particular button. Which should be possible if someone can find the id for that button. I don't have code for that other than the link to the msdn article in the comment above.

Comment: I am confused. How do you send your print to printer? You use MS Word, right? So you van get the print setting if you record a macro

Comment: No I am not sending printer to printer. Try recording a macro in Word 2013 for printing. It will not record the selection for both sides as in my screenshot. I think we need to stop going back and forth on this thread in comments because the moderators don't like us to have long conversations here. If you can find a way to program "print on both sides" then I would really appreciate it but don't keep asking questions because I'm serious and don't want to get this post taken down for violating rules.

Answer (score 1):

When you record a macro and print using the duplex options, it does not capture duplex in the dialog.
This is the macro that was generated when I double-sided a test document:

```
ActivePrinter = "\\MyServer\MyHPPrinter"
Application.PrintOut FileName:="", Range:=wdPrintAllDocument, Item:= _
        wdPrintDocumentWithMarkup, Copies:=1, Pages:="", PageType:= _
        wdPrintAllPages, Collate:=True, Background:=True, PrintToFile:=False, _
        PrintZoomColumn:=0, PrintZoomRow:=0, PrintZoomPaperWidth:=0, _
        PrintZoomPaperHeight:=0
```

During the recording of the Macro, the document printed duplex. When I closed/reopened the document and ran the Macro, it printed one-sided. Using Word from Office 365 and printing to HP Laser Jet9050dn. I also tried adding `, ManualDuplexPrint:=False` after wdPrintAllPages. This did nothing for me.

If this was formatted incorrectly, please forgive me.... this is my first post here.

Comment: Thanks Lobeon. The formatting looks pretty good. The only suggestion I would give is to put back-ticks around the part that you added instead of double-quotes, so it's clear that `, ManualDuplexPrint:=False` is "code."