# PDF printing on the back

Tags: vba, ms-access, pdf

In the "ACCESS" program, you need to print the active page of the form, and on the back of the sheet a PDF file (by hyperlink in this page). I have a duplex printer.

```
    Private Sub duplexprinter_Click()
Dim myform As Form
 Dim pageno As Integer
     pageno = Me.CurrentRecord
     Set myform = Screen.ActiveForm
DoCmd.SelectObject acForm, myform.Name, True
DoCmd.PrintOut acSelection, pageno, 1, , 1
      CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(0).ParseName(Me.path).InvokeVerb ("Print")
DoCmd.SelectObject acForm, myform.Name, False
End Sub
```

The printer perceives this code as 2 consecutive jobs, so it prints on 2 different sheets.

Please help me write the code to print on both sides of one sheet.

Comment: Does [How to select "print on both sides" in MS Word 2013 vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44052516/how-to-select-print-on-both-sides-in-ms-word-2013-vba) help?

Comment: The printer is set to duplex by default.

Comment: if i change the code: `DoCmd.PrintOut acSelection, pageno, 3, , 1`  prints: 1 sheet - on both sides; 2 sheet - on one side; 3 sheet - on one side (PDF)

Comment: You should have translated that statement into English. Why would you expect printer to do anything else? Default duplex setting is irrelevant. Possibility to send command to printer to hold page and flip for print on reverse instead of ejecting is unlikely. Review https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/34604-vba-print-pages-either-double-sided-single.html#:~:text=The%20short%20answer%20is%20no.%20Duplex%20options%20are,you%20to%20send%20instructions%20directly%20to%20the%20printer.

Comment: Best I can suggest is a message box alerting user to reinsert sheet flipped then when click OK send PDF to print. I know this would be impractical for a large printer machine located in a workroom 2 floors away but that's life. I did implement for small printer sitting near desk. Otherwise, convert PDF to jpg and embed in a report for printing instead of form.

Comment: I'm new at this. The question is, if (the active page of the form and the PDF file) to print to a temporary PDF, then this temporary PDF is printed on the printer without saving.

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

1. Print/[output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.outputto) the form to PDF:

```vb
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputForm, myform.Name, acFormatPDF, strFile1
```

2. Use a command-line tool like pdftk to combine file1 with the back side pdf.

https://superuser.com/questions/34284/combine-merge-pdf-files-in-windows

3. Print the result file.